# Retain column name case in a Athena json output

Tags: amazon-athena

I have a table in Athena and I am querying it to produce a json resultant file using CTAS queries. But the resultant json file is not maintaining the camel case of either the column name or the alias that was provided for the column name in the query.
Please suggest how i can overcome this issue.

For ex:

```json
{"email":"abc_def@ghi.com", "firstname": "abc", "lastname": "def"}
```

This should be coming up in the json file(result of the Athena query) as:

```json
{"email":"abc_def@ghi.com", "firstName": "abc", "lastName": "def"}
```

Query that I have tried:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users WITH (
    format = 'JSON',
    bucket_count = 1,
    bucketed_by = ARRAY [ 'lastName' ]
) AS
SELECT email,
    firstname as "firstName",
    lastname as "lastName"
from all_users;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately  JSON Format in CTAS does not support case sensitive Names.But you can use the below approach.Thats why snake case is preferred by our team.Below query is verbose but it will work

````
CREATE TABLE users WITH (
    format = 'TEXTFILE',
    bucket_count = 1,
    bucketed_by = ARRAY [ 'record' ]
) AS
SELECT json_format(CAST(MAP_FROM_ENTRIES( ARRAY[('email',CAST(email AS VARCHAR)), ('firstName',nullIf(firstname, 'null')), ('lastName',nullIf(lastName, 'null'))]) AS JSON)) as record FROM all_users ```
````